# How to integrate Fortify Scan in AWS CodeBuild (buildspec.yml)

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, fortify, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

My Company is right now running in Azure DevOps with AWS. We are planning to use AWS native tools, as part of this POC we are trying to integrate all the tools that we are currently using in AzDO. Im trying for the past 1week on how to *integrate Fortify Scanner* as part of *Code Build under buildspec.yml*.

Is there any specific way or sample buildspec.yml will be very helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run the Fortify scan using commands? If yes then you will need to install and run the same commands from CodeBuild buildspec. BuildSpec Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Comment: They have given in overview. im looking more specific and detailed thing